# Windows Azure Platform and multitenancy

Tags: azure, cloud, multi-tenant

Please tell me what is the relation between Windows azure and multitenacy application?

How to make multi tenant application?

It possible to host multi tenant application in windows azure platform?

Comment: Your question is so generic it is hard to approach without clarification.  What specifically interests you from multi-tenant perspective that worries you from Azure's point of view then from a regular non-cloud provider (or your own data center) point of view?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure is a platform upon which you can build web applications and services.  Windows Azure does not provide multi-tennancy support built-in (multiple separate clients using the same app instance but not sharing data between clients).

Your options are two write your application for single-tennancy and configure a new instance of that app for each client, or implement your app for multi-tennancy and handle user accounts and user separation internal to your app.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/appfabric/azure/product.aspx : "All services are multi-tenant - you simply provision, configure, and use, no management of machines/instances required". What does this mean? Cheers.

Comment: I believe that statement is referring only to the AppFabric services available to your Azure web application/service.  You don't have to set up a separate instance to use those AppFabric services, they are just available to your app running on the Azure platform.  The OP question here was about *hosting* a multitennant application on Azure, which is a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure does support multi tenancy, but you have to architect for it.

The most typical model I've seen used is a multi tenant web and business layer with a single tenant data store. You can debate multi tenant data, but single tenancy seems the preference from a risk perspective. If one client is compromised or corrupted, you don't want to affect all your customers.

You can do that quite easily by

1. Ensuring that your web and business
   components are stateless.
2. Use a common security layer
3. Switch data context per request

The data context switching is the most complex part, but it could be something as simple as having a per user/role Entity Connection string if you're using EF, or a Partition naming pattern if you're using Table storage.

Comment: Thanks for reply Doobi,i m new in multitenant and sharepoint, i want to host sharepoint foundation 2010 application in multi teant tell me about steps i read lots of article for this but not getting much more idea.Please help me in this task..

Comment: Sharepoint is a different story, I'm afraid I can't help you with that. If it's just as a hosting solution, Microsoft already offers cloud sharepoint hosting as part of 'BPOS', what will soon be renamed "Office 365"